# Django admin auto-save

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was asking myself how it would be possible to auto-save one of my models field I'm currently updating in the django admin every x seconds. For example, if I'm writing a blog post, I'd like it to be auto-saved every x seconds. That way, if I ever stupidly close the tab, I wouldn't lose all my work.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or any modules I wouldn't have found while my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HTTP is stateless, you have to use JavaScript for this task and submit the actual changes, nowadays it is called Ajax ;-)

Maybe you like [Dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/dajaxproject.com)

Comment: Nice, I'm gonna take a look to it ;)